# Running Powershell completely headless

Tags: php, windows, powershell, windows-10

i want to send a "Ballon Notification" to a remote computer in my network. Every machine in the network runs on windows 10.
The event needs to be triggered from a website which is build with php.
I've accomplished this by using the following code:

**php**

```
$powershell_path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
$script_path = "[..path to the ps1 script..]\\test.ps1";

$exec = $powershell_path." -executionPolicy Unrestricted ".$script_path." -computer_name ".$args['remote_computer'];
shell_exec($exec." 2>&1");
```

**test.ps1**

```
param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$computer_name
)

function Send-Balloon {

    Param(
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$To,
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$balloon_title,
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$balloon_text,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)][int]$show_time,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)][string]$scripts_path,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)][string]$script_name
    )

    if(!$show_time) { $show_time = 15000 }
    if(!$scripts_path) { $scripts_path = "C:\temp\" }
    if(!$script_name) { $script_name = "task.ps1" }

    $remote_computer = $To

    if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $remote_computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction     SilentlyContinue)) {
        Write-Warning "$remote_computer could not be reached"
        break
    }

    $str = @"
        Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Windows.Forms
        `$balloon = [System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon]::new()
        `$path = (Get-Process -id `$pid).Path
        `$balloon.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon(`$path)
        `$balloon.BalloonTipIcon  = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Info
        `$balloon.BalloonTipTitle = '$balloon_title'
        `$balloon.BalloonTipText  = '$balloon_text'
        `$balloon.Visible  = `$true
        `$balloon.ShowBalloonTip(100000)
    "@

    $script = [scriptblock]::Create($str)
    $script | Out-File $scripts_path\$script_name
    $remote_path = "\\$remote_computer\c$\temp"

    if(!(Test-Path $remote_path)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $remote_path
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $scripts_path\$script_name -Destination $remote_path

    $task_scriptblock = {
        $schedule_script = 'C:\temp\task.ps1'
        $seconds = 2
        $a = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-WindowStyle hidden -Command $schedule_script"
        $tr = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At ((Get-Date) + (New-TimeSpan -Seconds $seconds))
        $p = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -expand UserName)
        $tn = "!random_task_name_" + (-join ((65..90) + (97..122) | Get-Random -Count 10 | % {[char]$_}))
        $t = Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $tn -Trigger $tr -Action $a -Principal $p
        Start-Sleep ($seconds + 1)
        Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $tn | Unregister-ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false
        Remove-Item -Path $schedule_script
    }
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remote_computer -ScriptBlock $task_scriptblock 
}

Send-Balloon -To $computer_name -balloon_title "test" -balloon_text "just a test"
```

This code copies the script from $str into the tempfolder of a given remote computer. Afterwards it tolds the remote computer to execute the created file. After executing it deletes the ps1 file.

This works like intendet and (mostly) flawless. My problem now is, that powershell with '-WindowStyle hidden' is not really hidden. For a split second you can see the powershell console popping up and instantly vanishing.
I've read that this is the 'normal' behaviour and can be counteracted by calling the ps1-file from another context like a vbs script.

**vbs**

```
command = "powershell.exe -nologo -command [path to the ps1-file]"
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run command,0
```

The thing is, that this seems to be overcomplication everything as i do have a php script to run a ps1 script to copy a ps1 and a vbs file. Then call the copied vbs script, which calls the copied ps1 to show a simple notification.

Is there a simple method to call the ps1 script via php on a remote computer without seeing the powershell console? Or even better: is there is simpler way to trigger 'balloon notifications' on a remote computer which i haven't thought of yet?

Comment: Since `powershell.exe` is a console application, you can't prevent the console from appearing when you run it as the current user (even when using `-WindowStyle Hidden`) unless you start `powershell.exe` itself as a hidden window (which you have discovered).

Comment: i've now using the php script to copy a ps1 and a vbs file, and using a slightly modified powershell (see code above), to execute the the vbs for triggering the ps1...not the best solution but works like'ish i need it to be..thanks